# How to parse a scientific notation string value?

Tags: r

My test data

```
df1=structure(list(IdComponent = c(3725L, 3738L, 3833L, 3837L, 
3890L, 3899L, 5270L, 5275L, 5280L, 5285L, 5295L, 5310L, 5320L, 5374L, 5381L, 5575L), 
Value = c("18.60x10^3", "160.0x10^3", 
"20.70seg", "COMENTARIOseg", "1.78mg/dL", "34.11mg/dL", "0.70", 
"7.130", "55.6mmHg", "53.7mmHg", "3.48mmol/l", "202.80mg/dL", 
"79.7%", "-11.7mmol/l", "397.6mmHg", "1.30mg/dL")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

I need to parse only values which contain `x10^` so they are converted from string scientific notation to regular numeric values. The rest of the values to remain the same.

```
df2=structure(list(IdComponent = c(3725L, 3738L, 3833L, 3837L, 
3890L, 3899L, 5270L, 5275L, 5280L, 5285L, 5295L, 
5310L, 5320L, 5374L, 5381L, 5575L), 
Value = c(18600, 160000, 
"20.70seg", "COMENTARIOseg", "1.78mg/dL", "34.11mg/dL", "0.70", 
"7.130", "55.6mmHg", "53.7mmHg", "3.48mmol/l", "202.80mg/dL", 
"79.7%", "-11.7mmol/l", "397.6mmHg", "1.30mg/dL")), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-16L))
```

I tried `gsub('\\x10\\^', 'e', df1$Value)`, but it returned the same value.

Comment: I've posted a revised answer.  I do **strongly** encourage you to try to post your problem in its full version; it's more efficient to answer a question once rather than giving an answer that solves part of the problem you have, then come back to revise the answer after the question is updated ...  When editing, it would also be good to keep the partial solution from your previous version of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your more involved problem (convert only values containing 'x10\^', leave everything else as is) we need something like

```r
cfun <- function(x) {
   target <- 'x10\\^'
   if (!grepl(target, x)) return(x)
   as.character(as.numeric(gsub(target, 'e', x)))
}
df1$Value <- sapply(df1$Value, cfun)
```

Protecting the "x" with double backslashes is unnecessary.  (The substitution gives us "18.60e3", which is correctly converted by `as.numeric`; I then convert *back* to character because it will be included as part of a character vector.  This last step isn't strictly necessary because the same coercion would happen automatically ...)

```r
 df1$Value
 [1] "18600"         "160000"        "20.70seg"      "COMENTARIOseg"
 [5] "1.78mg/dL"     "34.11mg/dL"    "0.70"          "7.130"        
 [9] "55.6mmHg"      "53.7mmHg"      "3.48mmol/l"    "202.80mg/dL"  
[13] "79.7%"         "-11.7mmol/l"   "397.6mmHg"     "1.30mg/dL"
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to partially work. I have added more info to my initial question

Comment: Success! Thanks for adjusting to my newer requirement